# GAS Column Chart from spreadsheet data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

On [this link](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.in/2011/09/visualize-your-data-charts-in-google.html), a chart is prepared in GAS with hard-coded data and they have mentioned that you can get data from SpreadsheetApp.

Please can someone assist me - how to build datatable (columns, rows) in GAS Charts from spreadsheet.

I tried the following but was unsuccessful

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("myid");
var datatable = ss.getSheetByName("Chart sheet").getRange("A1:H4").getValues();

var chart = Charts.newColumnChart()      
  .setDataTable(dataTable)      
  .setRange(0, 40)
  .setTitle('Chart')
  .setLegendPosition(Charts.Position.BOTTOM)
  .setDimensions(600, 300)
  .build();
```

I have used the code as doGet function, the output returns the following error:-

```
Cannot call overloaded constructor setDataTable with parameters (object) because there is more than one matching constructor signature: interface (class) setDataTable(DataTableBuilder) interface (class) setDataTable(DataTableSource)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `getValues()` after getting the range (Line 2). To fix it just remove `getValues()`. You also have a typo in `setDataTable(dataTable)` the variable you declared is in lowercase: `datatable`*

See the code fixed bellow:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("myid");
var datatable = ss.getSheetByName("Chart sheet").getRange("A1:H4");

var chart = Charts.newColumnChart()      
  .setDataTable(datatable)      
  .setRange(0, 40)
  .setTitle('Chart')
  .setLegendPosition(Charts.Position.BOTTOM)
  .setDimensions(600, 300)
  .build();
```

The API can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/data-table-source).

* Credit to [@kbrizy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22057237/kbrizy) for noting the variable typo.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, the variable 'datatable' was invoked with a lowercase 't'. Its use in "setDataTable()" has an uppercase "T".

That was going to be the next error after fixing what br araujo addressed.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35370519)